# How do use only a certain word(s) of dataframe headings as the iterating varibale of a for loop through each heading?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've been trying to figure out a way in which to use only part of each column heading of a pandas dataframe as the iteration variable of a for loop.

Below is (hopefully) a very simplistic version of what I want to achieve:

Say i have the below dataframe, table[ ]:
(in reality the columns would be alot longer than just one entry for each)

| DAY 1 | DAY 2 | DAY 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1.5 | 2.3 | 4.5 |

now to work through the columns of Days 1-3 is fairly simple:

```
for i in range(len(table)):
    table["DAY 1"][i] = table["DAY 1"][i] * 2
    table["DAY 2"][i] = table["DAY 2"][i] * 2
    table["DAY 3"][i] = table["DAY 3"][i] * 2
```

so great, i can go through each column, multiplying each row by 2 (I know I could just multiple the whole column by 2 and that would be alot easier rather than each row at a time). But taking this a step further, suppose I now have multiple cars in my table, which looks something like this:

| CAR 1 DAY 1 | CAR 1 DAY 2 | CAR 1 DAY 3 | CAR 2 DAY 1 | CAR 2 DAY 2 | CAR 2 DAY 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.5 | 2.3 | 4.5 | 2.1 | 3.1 | 6.3 |

As I have now have two 'variables' in each column, the car number and the day number, I want to be able use the above code but iterate for each Car number. So with a list of the Car numbers:

```
car_list = ['CAR 1', 'CAR 2']
```

I want to use car_list as the iterating variable of a for loop to go through all the columns of the table - in my head the code should look something like this maybe?:

```
for j in car_list:
    for i in range(len(table)):
        table[[j],"DAY 1"][i] = table[[j],"DAY 1"][i] * 2
        table[[j],"DAY 2"][i] = table[[j],"DAY 2"][i] * 2
        table[[j],"DAY 3"][i] = table[[j],"DAY 3"][i] * 2
```

I hope i've managed to describe what I'm getting at... Any help would be really appreciated :) Thank you!

Comment: This is a perfect example of a time when a [`MultiIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html) will be extremely helpful. You could create a DataFrame where the first level of the column Index is the Car level, and the second level is the Day level. There are then many tools that allow you to easily align operations on specific days or cars, or select only the subsets you need for particular operations (i.e. multiply Car 1 by 8 and Car 2 by 12, and Day 1 by 50 but Day 20 by 17.123)

Comment: Hiya @ALollz, thank you for the comment! Yes this is something I am also looking into at the moment, but it requires me to change the format of my input data considerably, and there is already a very large pre-processing section of code. I may just go down the route of using a dictionary with each entry as a dataframe and iterate through the entries of the dictionary...

Answer (score 0):

That's how I understood the problem and how I would solve it:

```
car_list = ['CAR 1', 'CAR 2']
day_list = ['DAY 1', 'DAY 2']

for day in day_list:
  for car in car_list:
    column_name = day + " " + car
    table[column_name] = table[column_name] * 2
```

Comment: Hi Kelyen, Thank you for your answer - I have also tried changing my code so I could do the kind of thing youve illustrated but the code I have in my actual for loop is considerable and I cant really change it, i need the loop through the rows for what I am doing. Hence I'm looking for a solution which allows me to almost 'insert' the Car Number into the pre-existing code of the for loop, as another outside layer for loop if that makes sense?